WebSocket Connection Always Close in ASP.NET CORE 7
I currently build application for study Web API in ASP Net Core 7. So, I want to update automatically 2 values x and y by Web Socket. Here the API Quote Controller :
[HttpGet("ws")]
public async Task GetRealTimeQuote(int page=1,int limit = 10,string sector = "",string industry = "")
{
    if (HttpContext.WebSockets.IsWebSocketRequest)
    {
        using var webSocket = await HttpContext.WebSockets.AcceptWebSocketAsync();
        var random = new Random();
        while (webSocket.State == WebSocketState.Open)
        {
        
            int x = random.Next(1, 100);
            int y = random.Next(1, 100);
            var buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes($"{{ \"x\": {x}, \"y\": {y} }}");
            await webSocket.SendAsync(
                new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer),
                WebSocketMessageType.Text, true, CancellationToken.None);
            await Task.Delay(2000); // 
        }
    }
    else
    {
        
        HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest;
    }
}

The html file :
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>WebSocket Test</title>
</head>

<body>
    <script>
       
        const socket = new WebSocket(`wss://localhost:7154/api/Quote/ws`);

        socket.onopen = () => {
            console.log('Connected to the server via WebSocket');
        };
        socket.onmessage = (event) => {
            const quote = JSON.parse(event.data);
            console.log('Received quote:', quote);
            // Update the DOM with the received quote data
            document.getElementById('x-value').textContent = `X: ${quote.x}`;
            document.getElementById('y-value').textContent = `Y: ${quote.y}`;
        };
        socket.onclose = () => {
            console.log('Connection closed');
        };
        socket.onerror = (error) => {
            console.error('WebSocket error:', error);
        };
    </script>
    <h1>Test WebSocket, Show x, y in Real-Time</h1>
    <p id="x-value">X: </p>
    <p id="y-value">Y: </p>
</body>
</html>

In Program.cs I already use
var webSocketOption = new WebSocketOptions
{
    KeepAliveInterval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2)
};
app.UseWebSockets(webSocketOption);

The problem is the connection always have error. I used dev tool in browser I saw:

The localhost is correct. I still don't know why the connection always fail. Or is it because I left the file in the wrong folder. Here where I put the html file path. Or the way I open it is wrong way (Whenever I run the project, I go to the project folder and click on the HTML file, Is this causes the HTML file to be unable to connect to the WebSocket?)

run the html file using file:// protocol can cause issues with WebSocket connections. try to run html file using  http://localhost:YOUR_PORT/. if you are trying to access application from different origin make sure you have added cors code. try to move html file to the wwwroot folder. try to access webscoket url with ws://.

You could try below code:
QuoteController.cs:
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System.Net.WebSockets;
using System.Text;

namespace WebSocketExample.Controllers
{
    //[ApiController]
   // [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class QuoteController : ControllerBase
    {

        [Route("/ws")]

        public async Task GetRealTimeQuote(int page = 1, int limit = 10, string sector = "", string industry = "")
        {
            if (HttpContext.WebSockets.IsWebSocketRequest)
            {
                using var webSocket = await HttpContext.WebSockets.AcceptWebSocketAsync();
                var random = new Random();
                while (webSocket.State == WebSocketState.Open)
                {

                    int x = random.Next(1, 100);
                    int y = random.Next(1, 100);
                    var buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes($"{{ \"x\": {x}, \"y\": {y} }}");
                    await webSocket.SendAsync(
                        new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer),
                        WebSocketMessageType.Text, true, CancellationToken.None);
                    await Task.Delay(2000); // 
                }
            }
            else
            {

                HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest;
            }
        }
    }
}

Program.cs:
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("AllowLocalhost",
        builder =>
        {
            builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:5130", "https://localhost:7275")
                   .AllowAnyHeader()
                   .AllowAnyMethod()
                   .AllowCredentials();
        });
});

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

var webSocketOptions = new WebSocketOptions
{
    KeepAliveInterval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2),
    AllowedOrigins = { "http://localhost:5130", "https://localhost:7275" }
};

app.UseCors("AllowLocalhost");
app.UseWebSockets(webSocketOptions);
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapControllers();

app.Run();

wwwroot/index.html:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>WebSocket Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        const socket = new WebSocket('wss://localhost:7275/ws');

        socket.onopen = () => {
            console.log('Connected to the server via WebSocket');
        };

        socket.onmessage = (event) => {
            const quote = JSON.parse(event.data);
            console.log('Received quote:', quote);
            document.getElementById('x-value').textContent = `X: ${quote.x}`;
            document.getElementById('y-value').textContent = `Y: ${quote.y}`;
        };

        socket.onclose = (event) => {
            console.log('Connection closed', event);
        };

        socket.onerror = (error) => {
            console.error('WebSocket error:', error);
        };
    </script>
    <h1>Test WebSocket, Show x, y in Real-Time</h1>
    <p id="x-value">X: </p>
    <p id="y-value">Y: </p>
</body>
</html>

check this official sample:
https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/tree/main/aspnetcore/fundamentals/websockets/samples/7.x/WebSocketsSample

